# How to hide bash shell errors on the screen

Tags: bash

I have the small script:

```
if [ $proxy_chooice -eq 1 ]; then

echo 'Choose kinds of proxy\n 1)http 2) https 3)ftp'

read  proxyType
```

When user enters or writes words then enter.
It will write out

```
test.sh: 50: [: -eq: unexpected operator
```

I want to hide these errors what i can do. Thank you much.

Comment: Why would you hide the errors instead of fixing them? That's bad practice!

Comment: You should be able to pipe `stderr` (the error output) into the "null device" `/dev/null`. Just append a `2 > /dev/null` to the command line call of the script.

Comment: can you help me at in this script. I want check number only, I dont want users know script name. Thank you

Comment: You could use a `case` command to examine user input.

Comment: In your code you should probably quote the variable, as in `if [ "$proxy_chooice" -eq 1 ]`.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to suppress output, simply add 2>/dev/null:

```
$ rm non-existent-file
rm: cannot remove `non-existent-file`: No such file or directory
$ rm non-existent-file 2>/dev/null
$
```

But the correct way to handle your case would be to check if the variable you are trying to compare is not empty before the comparison...

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to `$proxy_chooice` not having a value (typo in variable name?).  The test therefore becomes

```
if [ -eq 1 ]; then
```

You may "fix" that by turning it into a string comparison instead (however, if this is just a case of a typo, then this means that the code within the `if`-statement wil *never* be executed):

```
if [ "x$proxy_chooise" = "x1" ]; then
```

Rather than "hiding" the error output, you should fix your code.

You also need to handle invalid input properly.

For example:

```
echo "You need proxying?"
select answer in  "Yes" "No"; do
    case $REPLY in
        1|2)    proxy_choice=$REPLY; break  ;;
        *)      echo "Please select 1 or 2" ;;
    esac
done
echo "$answer, sir!"

if [ $proxy_choice -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "What kind of proxy would you require?"

    select answer in "HTTP" "HTTPS" "FTP"; do
        case $REPLY in
            [1-3])  proxy_type=$REPLY; break    ;;
            *)      echo "Please select 1-3"    ;;
        esac
    done

    echo "An $answer proxy? Excellent!"
fi
```

Running:

```
You need proxying?
1) Yes
2) No
#? 3
Please select 1 or 2
#? 2
No, sir!
```

Second go:

```
You need proxying?
1) Yes
2) No
#? 1
Yes, sir!
What kind of proxy would you require?
1) HTTP
2) HTTPS
3) FTP
#? 4
Please select 1-3
#? 2
An HTTPS proxy? Excellent!
```